# Redirect stdin through GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, stdin, io-redirection

I have this very basic application that intends to evaluate given Python code on one `textEdit` component and show results on the other one.

```
import sys                                                                                                                                                                                      
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from cStringIO import StringIO

class SampleGUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SampleGUI, self).__init__()
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.code = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.result = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Evaluate')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.evaluate)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.code)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.result)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()

    def evaluate(self):
        source_code = str(self.code.toPlainText())
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
        exec source_code
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
        self.result.setText(redirected_output.getvalue())

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    s = SampleGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works well so far you don't ask for input values. Say you run the script from the console with `python samplegui.py`, if you happen to type something like this in the first text box:

```
a = 3
print 5 + a
b = input()
print 1 + b
```

and then push `Evaluate`, the application expects a value input **from the console**. After put some value and press enter it continues and evaluates correctly.

What a I want to achieve is to redirect the `stdin` to a component that I can manipulate from within the `GUI` itself.

How can I do that? Ideally I would like to do it in the Python interpreter style, where the output and input happens interactively. Another option could be to handle/capture somehow the signal when the application is waiting for input and show an input dialog.

**EDIT:**

It turned out that it was easier than I thought. Here you can see a version of the script with `sys.stdin` intercepted with a `QInputDialog` so the user can input values from `GUI`.

```
import sys 
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from cStringIO import StringIO

class InputGUI():
    def __init__(self, parentWidget):
        self.parentWidget = parentWidget

    def readline(self):
        text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self.parentWidget, 'Introduce value', 'Value:')
        if ok: 
            return str(text)
        else:
            return ''

class SampleGUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SampleGUI, self).__init__()
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.code = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.result = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Evaluate')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.evaluate)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.code)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.result)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()

    def evaluate(self):
        source_code = str(self.code.toPlainText())
        streams = sys.stdin, sys.stdout
        sys.stdin = InputGUI(self)                                                                                                                                                              
        redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
        exec source_code
        sys.stdin, sys.stdout = streams
        self.result.setText(redirected_output.getvalue())

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    s = SampleGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd replace `sys.stdin` with a an instance of a custom class that implements the file descriptor protocol. You can then simply decide what should happen when a user wants to read something via `input()` or `sys.stdin.readline()`.

As for implementing a file descriptor: implement all the methods covered in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects). Additionally, you might want to implement the [context manager protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager), so your custom `sys.stdin` can be used with a `with` statement.

Note, however, that users still can shoot themselves in the foot if they replace `sys.stdin` themselves again, but at least that seems more unlikely than someone calling `input()`.

Comment: Thank you for pointed me in the right direction @Christian Aichinger. I created a class that implements `readline()` that is the only method I need right now. Don't worry about re-replacing `sys.stdin`, I control the code to be evaluated (i.e. generated by a parser). I will edit the question to add the script modified so it will accept input from a `QInputDialog`.